# Vaadin IntelliJ cannot resolve symbol of two set methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vaadin

I'm trying to show a select list with two options, in this way...

```
List<String> typeUser = Arrays.asList("ADMIN", "USER");
ListSelect type = new ListSelect("Type", typeUser);
type.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
type.setRows(2);
```

But the two statements for setting the "type" variable shows me this error "cannot resolve symbol".

When I comment the two statements everything goes fine, but then select list allows me to select the empty option and the view looks like this...

[image]

... and that is something I clearly don't want.

What is the problem?

**EDIT**

This is what auto-completions shows me for "type" variable...

[image]

Comment: please show the full error message

Comment: The error appears in the two statements like cannot resolve symbol 'setNullSelectionAllowed' and cannot resolve symbol 'setRows'. Just that.

Comment: maybe the version of vaadin contains the class `ListSelect` , but the two methods don't exist.

Comment: how can't I check that? Because a search onto the [api of vaadin select list](https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.5/com/vaadin/ui/ListSelect.html) and the method appears.

Comment: I've already visited this page, too. Does IntelliJ auto completion suggest the methods when you enter `type.` ? Did you try a restart of IntelliJ? Did you invalidate the cache of IntelliJ? (menu `File`, then `Inavlidate Caches/Restart`)

Comment: Yes, I already try all of those. About the auto-completion, over "type" only appears these two (see the edit, please).

Comment: Hm, can you please try to change the name of the "type" variable? Because it's a little bit weird that the variable "type" is in purple color with yellowish background... it should be normal white color... the yellowish background suggest that there is some warning for that variable or something... I tried your code and it works ok for me... please paste whole class if you can...

Comment: this is the entire class, hope you can help [link](https://gist.github.com/doblesesays/6897790780c1a46a404415ccf38ecd7a)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem... Result that I put the set statements in the middle of a class declaration. Statements like this must be in methods or constructors. Dub >.<